# How to show Page # in HTML footer of table

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to display page numbers in footer of table in Chrome. But when i implement the CSS code of Counter example shown below. I do not get page numbers displayed. It gives me the same number repeated on all pages.

I tried the following code

```
<table>
<thead>
    some header here...
</thead>
<tbody>
    some rows here....
<tbody>
<tfoot>
    <div id="#pageFooter"></div>
</tfoot>
```

with CSS

```
table{
 counter-reset: page;
}
tfoot{
 display: table-footer-group;
}
#pageFooter:after{
 counter-increment: page;
 content: "Page " counter(page);
}
```

I also tried this approach

```
@page {
@bottom-left {
 content: counter(page)
 }
}
```

Please help me in figuring out the solution

Comment: You have a typo, it's `id="pageFooter"` without #

Answer (score 0):

Move `counter-reset: page;` from `<table>` to your `<body>` tag.

```
body{
    counter-reset: page;
}
```